# Restrict grafana user from creating any new folder

Tags: grafana, grafana-dashboard

We have several folders containing the dashboards. Each folder is meant for a specific team. The team-member can do what ever he/she wants to create within that folder only.
I know how to restrict a user to a particular folder but not sure how can I restrict a user from creating a new folder itself? For example if there are 5 teams and 5 folders (containing multiple Panels within them)  in the Dashboard view, the user within any team shouldn't be able to create 6th folder in dashboard except the Admin.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Grafana Admins can create, edit, or delete folders.

See more info at Grafana documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/permissions/organization_roles/).

Comment: Thanks Marcelo! This table was useful and I figured it out... Gave the viewer permission to all the users and gave edit for their respective folders. This way they couldn't create folders

Comment: Great, could you "accept" the answer then?